# Propagating insertions to multiple databases

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have a simple database of the following form :

```
   Users{
    UserID (PK)
    Username
    Email
    FirstName
    SecondName
   }

   Groups{
    GroupID (PK)
    GroupName
   }

   Membership{
    UserID (FK)
    GroupID (FK)
   }
```

Membership is the "go-between" for the other two tables. When a user registers, their Username is inserted into the Users and Groups table (creating a group by themselves). UserID and GroupID should reference the corresponding columns in `Users` and `Groups`.

Is the best way of doing this simply with three INSERT INTO statements when a user registers, like so :

```
if (db.Execute("INSERT INTO Users(Username, Email, FirstName, SecondName) VALUES(@0,@1,@2,@3)", username, email, firstName, secondName) < 1
                || db.Execute("INSERT INTO Groups(GroupName) VALUES(@0)", username) < 1
                || db.Execute("INSERT INTO Membership(UserID, GroupID) VALUES(@0, @1)",?????????????) < 1)
            {
                <p class="error">Wasn't able to insert User record</p>//insert failed
            }else {
            Response.Redirect("Success.cshtml"); //success
            }
```

What should I put in the third INSERT INTO statement so that it will insert the userID and corresponding groupID correctly?

Comment: Once again, why aren't you using a stored procedure for this? Then you can pass in the parameters and let the database deal with putting the IDENTITY values into the subsequent tables. I don't know why you would want to pull the values back into your application code just to send them back to the database.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks very much for your response again. To be honest with you, as a beginner I haven't worked with stored procedures before so I am tending to shy away from them! Thank you very much, I will definitely try this now. What kind of file should I create to store the code you have written below in? Apologies for the stupid question, as I said I am a beginner :).

Comment: You run the `CREATE PROCEDURE` script in a query window, against the database, using Management Studio. The second code sample should be run exactly the same way you are running the sample code you posted in your question.

Comment: Oh, I've just realised how it works! So stupid of me - I thought that the code was being saved in a file and ran to access the database (hence my shying away!). I understand it now; thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is database logic... put it in the database.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddUserAndGroup
  @username   NVARCHAR(255),
  @email      VARCHAR(320),
  @firstname  NVARCHAR(32),
  @secondName NVARCHAR(32)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @UserID INT, @GroupID INT;

  INSERT dbo.Users(Username, Email, FirstName, SecondName)
    SELECT @username, @email, @firstname, @secondname;

  SELECT @UserID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

  -- could probably simply rest with OUTPUT, just keeping it simple/consistent

  INSERT dbo.Groups(GroupName) SELECT @username;

  SELECT @GroupID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

  INSERT dbo.Membership(UserID, GroupID) SELECT @UserID, @GroupID;
END
GO
```

Now you should be able to say something like this (pardon me if I don't have your client syntax correct, but I'm trying to come close):

```
if (db.Execute("EXEC dbo.AddUserAndGroup @0,@1,@2,@3;", 
    username, email, firstName, secondName) < 1
{
  <p class="error">Wasn't able to insert User record</p>//insert failed
}
else
{
  Response.Redirect("Success.cshtml"); //success
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this answer - I have learnt more from this than I have in studying SQL for the past few days. So incredibly helpful. The data appears to get put into every database as I expected, however it also always seems to return 0, however, so it always says there is an error. Is there any way to fix this? Thank you very much again :)

Comment: Change your check from `< 1` to `<> 0`. In SQL Server, a stored procedure returns 0 for success and a non-zero error code if there is an error.